# PHP pdo bindParam type management

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the post form:

```
 $funcname->name= htmlentities($_POST['name']);
 $funcname->insert();
```

this will be the function insert on class **funcname** which will insert the data to column named **name**

```
$this->conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO nameTBL (name) values (:name)";
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
         $this->conn->commit(); //This will save your changes
         $this->conn->exec('UNLOCK TABLES ' . self::$table_name);
         header('Location: ../');
         exit();
} else {
         $this->conn->rollBack(); //This will undo your changes
         $this->conn->exec('UNLOCK TABLES ' . self::$table_name);
         header('Location: ../');
         exit();
}
```

Now question is i have set  *PDO::PARAM_INT* which should not allow characters but only integer why i am able to post text to database(table)?

is there any  how i can highly restrict the data type on bindParam here.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several mistakes in your code.

However, let's go over what the types `PDO::PARAM_INT`, `PDO::PARAM_STR` and `PDO::PARAM_NULL` are telling MySQL to do.

Those values are telling PDO how to **treat** the input, not to **disallow** input. If you send text, but the column is `int` then MySQL will attempt to coerce the data into `int`. It won't tell you "you entered abcd but expected value was integer". You must do this check on your own before passing data to `PDO`.

Now onto other problems:

- Don't use `bindParam`. `bindParam` accepts the value by **reference**. This is intended for when you invoke stored procedures and variable is supposed to be modified based on procedure's output. Use `bindValue`. If you tried to do the following with `bindParam`, it wouldn't work and you'd get an error:

  `$stmt->bindParam(':my_column', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT); // It fails and yields an error`
- Don't lock tables. You're already using transactions, no need to lock the table, MySQL handles concurrency and access for you.

Bottom line - perform validation **before** using `PDO` for inserting. `PDO` helps you clean the input based on connection information (among other things). It won't perform validation.

Comment: dear but with bindParam i dont get any error,simply the text value gets into database, even the type on MySQL column is text here it should not execute the statement because, i have set the PDO type to int. so you mean should i use bindValue, which one is better and secure or both are same?

Comment: `bindValue` and `bindParam` are not the same. Both are equally "secure", and both will clean the input for insertion into query. Both have similar function signature. In your case, you can simply switch `bindParam` with `bindValue`. The two functions treat the **2nd** parameter differently. If you are doing only trivial queries (if you never invoke stored procedures) then use `bindValue`. If the column is of textual type, **don't** use `PDO::PARAM_INT`. It's not how it works and it's not for that purpose. If you want an integer, perform coercion in php (use `(int)$variable`).

Comment: with $stmt->bindValue(':name',$this->name,, PDO::PARAM_INT);,,, when i insert the text it will insert (0) instead..? is ok?

Comment: --for the table locking and transaction, with only $this->conn->beginTransaction(); it's ok for transaction as her are more then 1000 users are having transaction on one table of database will it prevent duplicating or error while if duplicate

Comment: To prevent duplicates, use `UNIQUE` keys. Locking a table won't prevent duplicates.

Comment: so i have 1000 users inserting in a single table how i can prevent any(duplicat, error, delay...etc) in mysql , thanks

Comment: Please clarify, are you asking about errors or duplicates or what? You prevent duplicate entries by setting `UNIQUE` index on a column or combination of columns. You don't do it by locking..